# how to rename multiple git branches into lowercase using bash

Tags: bash, git, shell, awk

I want to rename multiple branches in lowercase, as before migration we have to convert all uppercase branches to lowercase.
git branch:

```
CPORT_121

GC_211

Lower-Upper_DEMO
```

Now I tried the below one but it is not working.

```
git branch | tr A-Z a-z | xargs -n 2 git branch -m

error: refname refs/heads/cport_121 not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
fatal: '*' is not a valid branch name.
```

Comment: The thing is, git adds an `*` to the currently checked out branch (which you can't rename anyway). `git branch | grep -v '\*' | tr A-Z a-z | xargs -n 2 git branch -m` could probably do the trick (ignore line with `*` in it; don't try to rename current branch).

Comment: Also, just by the way: `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` would be an alternative to `tr A-Z a-z`

Comment: Alternatively to using and tweaking `git branch` output, use `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads` instead. No "*" there.

Comment: @roman - I think what you are mentioning is somewhat close to the resolution. But that is not working with same error "error: refname refs/heads/cport_121 not found".

Comment: The `-m'  option requires two arguments: The old branch name and the new one. You apply only one argument. Alternatively, you have to  `checkout` the branch to me renamed, and then use only `git -m NEWNAME`. In both cases, an explictit  loop would probably be easier than forcing this into `xargs`.

Comment: @user1934428 - I am doing checkout only as I have 100's of branches..for abranch in $(git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | grep remotes | sed "s/remotes\/origin\///g"); do git checkout $abranch ; done
and then I am able to do modifications for all branches except the lowercase conversion. for eg. git branch | grep -e [.]|awk '{original=$1; sub("[.]","-"); print original, $1}' | xargs -n 2 git branch -m
Here I can change all branches which has (.)- dot present and replaced with (-) hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to code the loop.  (Your checkout loop in the comments is also not really the right way to go.)  For script purposes we should use `git for-each-ref` whenever possible, and here it's entirely possible.  We would start with this, if we want to create local branch names for each `refs/remotes/origin/*` remote-tracking name that needs renaming:

```bash
git for-each-ref \
  --format="%(if)%(symref)%(then)%(else)%(refname:strip=3)%(end)" \
  refs/remotes/origin | sed '/^$/d' > /tmp/branchlist
```

This creates a file (`/tmp/branchlist`) containing all the remote-tracking names.  The `if/then/else/end` sequence drops the `HEAD` symbolic ref and the `sed` cleans out the corresponding blank line (not strictly necessary, but useful).

Some of these branch names might already be fine!  We probably don't want to fuss with those.  So now we can `grep` for uppercase:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -E '^[A-Z]+$' /tmp/branchlist > /tmp/upper
```

The `LC_ALL` here is necessary in case your grep uses POSIX collation (mine does on at least some systems).

It's now probably wise to inspect `/tmp/upper` to make sure that none of the names in it also appear as lowercase in `/tmp/branchlist`.  This is a one-time manual operation, but you can automate it if you like:

```
tr A-Z a-z < /tmp/upper | grep -F -f - /tmp/branchlist
```

Note that this will erroneously match substrings, e.g., if there's a "bad" name `OOPS` and a "good" name `whoops`, this will find the "good" name even though it's different; fixing that is harder and I won't bother.

We now want to create, in our local repository, one lowercase-name branch whose name matches the uppercase name:

```
awk '{ print "git branch --no-track " tolower($0) " refs/remotes/origin/" $0 }' \
  < /tmp/upper
```

Make sure this generates the desired commands and then pipe into `sh`:

```
awk '{ print "git branch --no-track " tolower($0) " refs/remotes/origin/" $0 }' \
  < /tmp/upper | sh
```

and we've generated the desired branch names.

Rather than creating such branch names, though, it makes more sense to me to run a `git push` command that creates the names directly *on* the remote.

To do that, we want:

```
git push origin
```

followed by a series of local remote-tracking names and the desired branch names: for each uppercase name, we want a lowercase-ified version of that name as a branch name.  So that would be:

```
(printf "git push origin"
awk '{ printf(" %s:%s", "refs/remotes/origin/" $0, "refs/heads/" tolower($0)) }' \
  < /tmp/upper
echo "")
```

Verify that this produces the desired `git push` command, then pipe to sh.

You may wish to `git push --delete` the uppercase-only names later; it should now be obvious how to do this.  After that, other users of this repository might want to run `git fetch --prune` to update their remote-tracking names.

Answer (score 1):

I will try but I'm really afraid about actions like this :|. So, be careful and ensure you are not going to loose your data.

```
# Create three random branches for the test
git branch www_FUNK0 origin/master
git branch WWW_funk1 origin/master
git branch WWW_FuNk2 origin/master

git branch | grep -i www_funk
# This is the output of this command:
#  www_FUNK0
#  WWW_funk1
#  WWW_FuNk2

# Iterating through all WWW_FUNK* branches one by one
for b in $(git branch | grep -i www_funk | tr -d ' ')
do 
    # Storing the $b branch into the tmp branch and then
    # delete $b branch
    # and rename tmp branch to the lowercase version of $b
    git checkout -B tmp $b
    git branch -D $b
    git branch -m ${b,,}
done

git checkout master
git branch -D tmp

git branch | grep -i www_funk
# Finally we have this result:
#  www_funk0
#  www_funk1
#  www_funk2
```

Please do not try those drills in a repo with useful data!!!

Comment: Here you have hardcoded grep www, what if you have even a single letter in uppercase. Based on regex on all letters between A-Z we have to lowercase not on WWW.

Comment: Hi @Time! Thank you for your time to review my answer and for your comment! you are right! I created a few branches with the keyword `WWW_FUNK` at the beginning of the branch name just to be sure that I'm not going to destroy the actual repo I was working at the moment. Initially I tested the script using `WWW_FUNK*` branches and posted the script but later added some changes in order to be clear that the approach works with mixed lowercase and uppercase too and then I forgot to change the safeguard filter. So, `grep -i www` do the job as well.  I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: when I am doing git branch -m $k feature-$k => all the branches renamed with feature- , however I am doing feature/  some branches renamed and some missed..any inputs will be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch --format='%(refname:short)' \
| sed -n '/[A-Z]/s/.*/git branch -m & \L&/p'
```

to do branches; if you want other refs you'll have to get more finicky about it, for instance changing remote-tracking names locally won't do anyone any good at all, you need to push the update:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(if)%(symref)%(then)%(else)%(refname:short)%(end)'  \
        refs/remotes \
|  sed -nr 's,([^/]*)/(.*),git push \1 refs/remotes/&:refs/heads/\L\2,p'
```

and then `git fetch --prune`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **bash**, here are two ways to **parse branch names correctly**.

**Simple way:** Read the branch list line by line, relying on the fact that branch names can't contain new lines:

```
git branch --format '%(refname:lstrip=-1)' |
while IFS= read -r name; do
    git branch -m "$name" "${name,,}"
done
```

**"Proper" way:** Use `git for-each-ref`, with `--shell` option to safely quote each name, such that it can be `eval`ed. The quoted names can be added to an array, to loop over:

```
eval "names=($(
    git for-each-ref refs/heads \
    --format '%(refname:lstrip=-1)' \
    --shell
))"

for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    git branch -m "$name" "${name,,}"
done
```

- The format string strips parent directories from the branch name (`refs/heads`).
- For `git branch`, it also prints names only, without the leading spaces and asterix.
- `${name,,}` is bash syntax to lowercase all characters in the variable.
- I prefer the first command, as it's simpler and less error-prone.
- Note that if you manually renamed the file `refs/heads/branch-name` to contain a new line, git refuses to list that branch and prints a broken name error (for both `git branch` and `git for-each-ref`). That is good.
- Both these commands require bash, and won't work in `/bin/sh`.